# Why can't I subdivide?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, geometry

Sometimes, when I add a face with the "F" key in Blender, I'm unable to subdivide that face further. For example, observe the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9UkpsXGVd8&feature=youtu.be

Why am I unable to subdivide that face? What should I do to be able to subdivide it? I'm using Blender 2.81.

Comment: Possibly turn off "create N-gons"?

Comment: Where and how does one do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blender is subdividing the edges on the outer edge of the face, but it isn't filling in the grid tiles for you.

[image]

If you want to fill in the top face with a grid using the subdivided vertices, first delete the top face. Then select the top edge loop, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> then select *Grid Fill.*

Answer (score 2):

### You are subdividing an N-gon

Faces with more than 4 edges are called n-gon. While subdividing a quad based topology leads to a subdivision of the face in four quadrants for each face like you expect, n-gons have a non trivial solution to the subdivision problem.

The solution of the operator implementation is to subdivide the external bondary edges. You can see the result if you switch to vertex selection mode.

*If your objective is to fill the upper face with small quads, the grid fill operator is probably the way to go.*