# Blender Subdivide function works randomly. It can divide or not depending on unknown reason

Tags: edges

Here is a problem

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=851HPiQ0RaU&feature=youtu.be

Whenever I try to use Subdivide in Blender it works randomly. Tryed on different machines, result is same. Randomly subdive some of Edges, some not.

Please tell me what I do wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Carlo's answer is what you're looking for here : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164019/why-cant-i-subdivide